# C# nested class List<>

Tags: c#

I  have C# classes below and would like to create a list of different families based on the address that the person lives.  If they have the same address, they are family.  So it should have a list of families and each family has a list of family members.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public Address address;

        public Person(string f, string l, string addr, string city, string state)
        {
            firstName = f;
            lastName = l;    
            address= new Address(addr, city, state);
        }
    }

   public class Family
    {
        public string familyAddress;//maybe I don't need this
        public List<Person> personList;

        public Family()
        {
            personList = new List<Person>();
        }

        public void AddPerson(Person p)
        {
            personList.Add(p);
        }

        public string FamilyAddress //maybe I dont need this
        {
            get
            {
                return familyAddress;
            }
            set
            {
                familyAddress= value;
            }
        }
    }

   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Family> familyList;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            familyList= new List<Family>();
            ReadCustomerFile("..\\Customers.txt");
        }

        private void ReadCustomerFile(file)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);                
            var reg = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                var data = reg.Matches(lines[i]).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

                //data[0] contains first name
                //data[1] contains last name
                //data[2] contains street
                //data[3] contains city
                //data[4] contains state

            //In here as I read the customer text file, i would 
            //like to add the person that has the same address into 
            //the same family.
            //for example:
            //familyList address: "800 NE Oregon St.  Portland, OR" has
            //                     "Steve Jones"
            //                     "Sarah Jones"
            //                     "Alisa Jones"

            //familyList address: "2525 Lake Park. Salt Lake City, UT" has
            //                     "Joey William"
            //                     "Becky William"
            //                     "Sam William"
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE#1- based on Tempx comment: Thank!

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Family> familyList;
        public List<Person> personList;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            familyList= new List<Family>();
            personList = new List<Person>();                

            ReadCustomerFile("..\\Customers.txt");
        }

        private void ReadCustomerFile(file)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);                
            var reg = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                var data = reg.Matches(lines[i]).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

                //data[0] contains first name
                //data[1] contains last name
                //data[2] contains street
                //data[3] contains city
                //data[4] contains state
                Person person = new Person(data[0].Trim(','),
                                            data[1].Trim(','),
                                            data[2].Trim(','),
                                            data[3].Trim(','),
                                            data[4].Trim(','));
                personList.Add(person);
            }

            //In here as I read the customer text file, i would 
            //like to add the person that has the same address into 
            //the same family.
            //for example:
            //familyList address: "800 NE Oregon St.  Portland, OR" has
            //                     "Steve Jones"
            //                     "Sarah Jones"
            //                     "Alisa Jones"

            //familyList address: "2525 Lake Park. Salt Lake City, UT" has
            //                     "Joey William"
            //                     "Becky William"
            //                     "Sam William"

            var familyAddress = new Dictionary<Address, Family>();
            Family family;
            foreach (Person p in personList)
            {
                // Returns true if the familyAddess contains the address of the person
                if (familyAddress.TryGetValue(p.address, out family))
                    //if such family exists add the person the family  
                    family.AddPerson(p);
                else // no family is found with the person's address
                {
                    //create a new family
                    family = new Family();
                    //add person to the family
                    family.AddPerson(p);
                    //add the family to the familyAddress dictionary
                    familyAddress.Add(p.address, family);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This statement

```
if (familyAddress.TryGetValue(p.address, out family))
```

always returns family not exists so it goes to else statement

UPDATE# 2- now can add person to the family.  But now sometime person has address that has comma and period in their address even though the street name, city and state are the same.  So it leads to Dictionary key TryGetValue() returns unwanted results.  Is it possible for TryGetValue() to ignore comma and period?  Thanks

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Family> familyList;
        public List<Person> personList;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            familyList= new List<Family>();
            personList = new List<Person>();                

            ReadCustomerFile("..\\Customers.txt");
        }

        private void ReadCustomerFile(file)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);                
            var reg = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                var data = reg.Matches(lines[i]).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
                Person person = new Person(data[0].Trim(','),
                                            data[1].Trim(','),
                                            data[2].Trim(','),
                                            data[3].Trim(','),
                                            data[4].Trim(','));
                personList.Add(person);
            }

            var familyAddress = new Dictionary<string, Family>();
            Family family;
            foreach (Person p in personList)
            {
                // Returns true if the familyAddess contains the address of the person
                if (familyAddress.TryGetValue(p.address.GetAddress(), out family))
                    //if such family exists add the person the family  
                    family.AddPerson(p);
                else // no family is found with the person's address
                {
                    //create a new family
                    family = new Family();
                    //add person to the family
                    family.AddPerson(p);
                    //add the family to the familyAddress dictionary
                    familyAddress.Add(p.address, family);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

UPDATE#3- I decided to format the address string into correct format before I add as Key in Dictionary.  After converting to List like below following Tempx suggestion:

```
var valueList = familyAddress.Values.ToList();
```

How can I traverse the list?  Because I try the below:

```
        foreach (var h in valueList)
        {
            foreach(var p in h)
            {
               //I cannot access the Person data?
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "It should have a list of Families and each Family should have a list of Family members." It looks like your code already has this.

Comment: You appear to have failed to ask a question. I have one for you though - why is `Address` represented as a string in one class and as an actual type in the other?

Comment: and what is public Household() in your class family?

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.  I just finish editing the post.  thanks.

Comment: string Address, maybe i don't need it because the familyList can access to Person where it has address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you would like to add the person to the correct family and believe you can use dictionaries to do the work.

```
public List<Person> personList;

//a specific address points to a specific family
var familyAddress = new Dictionary<Address, Family>();
```

At the beginning I am assuming that the personList is not empty but familyAddress is.

Then, in your code a for statement for a list of persons can be written as

```
foreach (person p in personList)
{   
    // Returns true if the familyAddess contains the address of the person
    if (familyAddress .TryGetValue(p.Address, out family))
        //if such family exists add the person the family  
        family.AddPerson(p);
    else // no family is found with the person's address
    {
      //create a new family
      family = new Family();
      //add person to the family
      family.AddPerson(p);
      //add the family to the familyAddress dictionary
      familyAddress.add(p.Address, family);
    }
}
```

You can retrieve a list of families as

```
familyAddress.Values.ToList();
```

PS:As the other commenters stated I also believe in the Family class familyAddress should be type of Address.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I thought about using Dictionary but I declared the structure wrong, Dictionary<string, List<Person>> so I was unable to add the person to the list that has the same address, key.  So I will try you suggestion tomorrow.  again thanks.

Comment: It seems this " if (familyAddress .TryGetValue(p.Address, out family))" does not return correctly because I check both addresses in familyAddress and p.Address in debugging mode, they are the same address, but the condition goes to the "else" statement.

Comment: the addresses may be the same but are they same objects? For example Address a1 and Address a2 may contain the same addresses but since they are different objects I believe TryGetValue may not work. I am sorry for this. What you can try is that instead of Address object as the key of the dictionary, you can use its string value. (In this case you may add a static method to the Address class such as toString() which converts the Address to its string equivalent.)

Comment: For Address to work as a Key in Dictionary it must override .GetHashCode() and .Equals()

Comment: @tempx, I just added the update in the post above based on your first suggestion.  I wanted to share the code to make sure, I don't screw up that leads to the wrong return in " if(familyAddress .TryGetValue(p.Address, out family)) " statement.  Thanks.

Comment: @Zoran Basic, great suggestion, but if override those methods, I'm not sure if I can cover all the cases.  So I'm just going to keep the code simple.

Comment: @tempx, I follow your 2nd suggestion. I declare Dictionary key as string, then Address class, I add a function to get the full address by concatenating street, city, and state. So now I can add person with same address to family. However is it possible in this "if (familyAddress.TryGetValue(p.address.GetAddress(), out family))" to compare string, but ignore the lower/upper case and other symbols like ". , - ~" ? because sometimes people write their address using comma or period other symbols after street or apartment unit.

Comment: I dont seem to be able to access data in Person class after converting to List, "var valueList = familyAddress.Values.ToList();"  Any help is very appreciated.  thanks.

Comment: @Phil based on your third update the code should be foreach (var h in valueList)
        {   
            foreach(var p in h.personList) //you would like to reach personList inside the family h, not the h itself
            {
               //I cannot access the Person data?
            }
        }

Comment: @tempx, Yep, I'm able to access the person fields now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use LINQ instead, you can transform a `List<Person>` into a `List<Family>` via LINQ.  Here's an extension method that will do just that:

```
public static class FamilyExtensions
{
    public static List<Family> GroupToFamilies(this List<Person> personList)
    {
        var retval = from p in personList
                     group p by new p.address into f
                     select new Family() { personList = f.ToList() }; //If familyAddress was of type Address, you could add: familyAddress = f.Key
        return retval.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can just call your method in your code wherever...

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

people.Add(new Person("Papa", "Bear", "123 Forest Rd", "Somewhere", "AK"));
people.Add(new Person("Mama", "Bear", "123 Forest Rd", "Somewhere", "AK"));
people.Add(new Person("Some", "Bear", "567 Woodland Ln", "Somewhere", "AK"));
people.Add(new Person("Other", "Bear", "890 Canopy Cr", "Somewhere", "AK"));

var families = people.GroupToFamilies();
```

Note that if you want to group by `p.address`, you will need to override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object obj)` on your `Address` class. If you don't want to override these two methods, you can alternatively group by a composite key:

```
from p in personList
group p by new { p.address.addr, p.address.city, p.address.state } into f
select new Family() { personList = f.ToList() };
```

If you do want to group by `Address`, override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object obj)` on your `Address` class like so...

```
public class Address
{
    /*** Rest of your class ***/

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var address = obj as Address;

        return address != null
            && address.addr == this.addr
            && address.city == this.city
            && address.state == this.state;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 41;
        hash = (hash * 79) + addr.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 79) + city.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 79) + state.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

[Here's more information on the group clause in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  LINQ will be in my future self study topic, but for now I want to keep the code simple.  thanks.